# How to pass a fortran ordered 2d numpy array into c++ using SWIG

Tags: python, c++, arrays, numpy, swig

I have a function in c++

```
myfun(double* array, int n1, int n2);
```

that I interface with numpy in python. In my interface file I have

```
%apply (double* INPLACE_FARRAY2, int DIM1, int DIM2) {(double* inarray, int n1, int n2)}
```

Now, I want to pass an array `b = array([[3,27.0],[2,9],[10,1]],order='F')` into myfun within python, but I get the following error

```
TypeError: Array must be contiguous.  A non-contiguous array was given.
```

What am I doing wrong? Is the double data type in my `%apply` statement incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Fortran order (order='F') may be the issue, since this is opposite the C order, I'm not sure because I'm unable to find a clear definition of continguous vs non for numpy. So it may be worth trying:

```
b = array([[3,27.0],[2,9],[10,1]],order='C')
```

Also, it may be worth trying

```
myfun( numpy.ascontiguousarray(b) )
```

I found the [numpy swig reference doc](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/swig.interface-file.html) useful to understand the difference between `INPLACE_` and `IN_` typemaps. Basically the latter is used when c function will only read and not write, as long input is a sequence of some sort the SWIG code will be able to handle it. The former indicates that the c function will write to the array so the ordering in original container is must match.

Comment: Good idea but it didn't work. I've been trying for a while and there may be no way to do this unless I manually move the elements so that it is in column-major format.

Comment: @user1589038 Something is not right, this is a basic case. What did you try for ascontiguousarray? I had wrong syntax, is the updated version what you tried?

Comment: I got this to work by passing ascontiguousarray(b) into myfun. However, when I change the SWIG interface to take in IN_FARRAY2 instead of INPLACE_FARRAY2 I can simply pass b, which is fortran contiguous. Why the difference?

Comment: user1589038 Makes sense that `in` version would work without `ascontiguousarray`, I have updated my answer hth.